# .classpath file is preventing a git rebase

Tags: java, git

I am trying to rebase my branch to master in order to grab some important changes that were done by a coworker on the same project. However, I have an eternal ".classpath" change that will not go away which is preventing a rebase.

When I use the command

```
git rebase master
```

I get this

```
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

I checked my code base for changes. The only change that has not been committed or stashed is a ".classpath" file. I am not too familiar with how these files work, but we can not include .classpath changes to any commit. So I discarded the changes. However, when I ran the command again I still got the same error. Looking through the project for changes shows that the ".classpath" changes have magically returned.

I tried staging the changes and then stashing them, figuring I can get rid of them after the rebase. Still no good. I could stash 100 times and the changes continue to appear.

I tried staging the changes without committing or stashing just to see what would happen and as I expected:

```
Cannot rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

I even get the error if I use

```
 git rebase master --force
```

This is incredibly perplexing, and I can not find a way to discard the ".classpath" changes without having them inexplicably return like a stray cat I made the mistake of feeding.

If you know how to get rid of these changes (or permanently banish them to whatever alternate dimension they keep returning from) please help me out.

Comment: `.classpath` is created and maintained by Eclipse. Close Eclipse, discard the changes, then do the rebase. Eclipse will then meddle with the file again when you start it, but now you don't care anymore. Though you should, because why can't you check in the file? What is it that eclipse adds that you don't want others to have? Why does you Eclipse need that and others don't?

Comment: I am honestly not sure what the changes to the file do, but we have a policy of not including any eclipse files in our commits because some people use other IDE's. Same reason that many companies ignore Mac specific files in their git repos. Honestly, I should just ask them to add .classpath files to our git ignore file. 

Closing eclipse, discarding the file and doing the rebase worked. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Generally**, you should be good to ignore the changes to the .classpath file. The IDE should create/maintain it again, if it is creating another one just after you revert changes, you can close your IDE. I hate the eclipse and the others based on it doing such things.

Comment: Using this command didn't work, but closing the IDE did. If you remove the command I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Edited the answer. The reason the `git checkout .classpath`  command does not work is, in the instant you make a change to it, your IDE updates it again. I tried renaming the file and in that instant IDE created a new default one.